# ¿Existen otras formas de referirse a uno mismo, aparte de "yo", registradas en el DLE?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, pronombres, dle, persona-gramatical

Cuando me puse a estudiar japonés me llamó la atención la cantidad de formas que tienen para referirse a uno mismo: *ore*, *boku*, *atashi*, *watashi*, *watakushi*... todas significan *yo* pero cada una es diferente según el estilo del habla, desde la más coloquial hasta la más formal. Y formas de *tú* las hay hasta despectivas, pero eso es otra cuestión.

El caso es que en español, que yo recuerde, solo contamos con el pronombre *[yo](https://dle.rae.es/?w=yo&m=form)*. Y pensando un poco también tenemos registrado *[menda](https://dle.rae.es/?w=menda&m=form)*, que no es un pronombre sino un sustantivo, pero que según el DLE "designa a la persona que habla". Su uso parece restringido solo a España, en todo caso, y se avisa de que su uso es solo en tercera persona, pero aun así me vale. El ejemplo que cita el propio DLE es el siguiente:

> No pienso ayudarles: menda ya no hace más favores.

¿Existen otros pronombres, sustantivos, expresiones, locuciones o lo que sea, aparte de los mencionados, registrados en el DLE, el DAMER o en diccionarios históricos, que sirvan para referirse a uno mismo, ya sean o fueran de uso generalizado o regional?

Comment: [Servidor](https://dle.rae.es/?w=servidor&m=form)

Comment: Probablemente no valga, pero en un tiempo estuvo de moda en Argentina usar la frase “este cuerpito” en lugar del pronombre. Muy restringido, eso sí: “Este cuerpito se va a dormir una siesta.”

Comment: Mathematicians in English use we to mean I as in "So we can see that ..." and according to the DLE Spanish does the same for nosotros. I am afraid i lack the skill to enter this in Spanish in the CW but if someone can pick it up (if they agree with the usage of course).

Comment: @mdewey yes, this is also used in Spanish. We tend to use a form like _luego se ve que..._, but at the same time demonstrations end with either the Latin QED or _como queríamos ver_ / _como se quería demostrar_ ([reference](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quod_erat_demonstrandum)).

Comment: @mdewey bear in ming that scientific papers are usually signed by more than one person. The use of "we" in those papers is to include every author of the paper in the sentence. Maybe the use of "we" even when the author is only one person reflects that the author wants to include the whole scientific community in the paper: _so we [the scientific community] can see that..._

Answer (score 4):

Reúno en un post *community-wiki* las respuestas que habéis ido dando en los comentarios. Sentíos libres de ir añadiendo cualquier otra que se os ocurra:

- *[Servidor](https://dle.rae.es/?w=servidor&m=form)*. Usado por la persona que habla para designarse a sí misma.
- *[Uno](https://dle.rae.es/?w=uno&m=form)*. Designa al hablante.
- *[Este cura](https://dle.rae.es/cura#6DL0rlf)*. Yo, la persona que habla.

Todas estas formas requieren que la frase esté en tercera persona.

- *[nosotros/nosotras](https://dle.rae.es/nosotras?m=&e=)*. Usado en textos científicos.

Mención especial a *[nos](https://dle.rae.es/?w=nos&m=form)*. "Usado en la actualidad solo por ciertas personas de muy elevado rango o dignidad, como reyes, papas u obispos", según el DLE, pero la definición que da es "nosotros" y no "yo".

Answer (score 2):

Se puede agregar que se suele usar la prase *"quien les habla*" [ver ejemplo](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=IPCzZozj7dEC&pg=PA203&dq=%22quien+les+habla%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLnoqDtfblAhXgJ7kGHfFzDMk4ChDoAQgnMAA#v=onepage&q=%22quien%20les%20habla%22&f=false) en sustitución de **yo**

> Estaba todos los profesores ahí y ***quien les habla***

---

En Argentina contextualmente  (y de manera coloquial) también se usa decir "papá", cuando quien se alude a sí mismo (en forma jactanciosa) es varón

> - Y ¿quien crees que se ganó el premio mayor esa noche levantándose [ligándose] a la más linda...?
>
> No ¿quién?
>
> - ¡**papá**!